# how to format/display resultset results in textbox properly?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to render data from database in textbox but its not displaying well its adding new line and white space..?

code

```
   <td width="200">
   <textarea rows="3" cols="25" style="text-align: left;>
      <%
         sql5 = "SELECT ip FROM user_ip WHERE username = ? ";
         ps5 = connection.prepareStatement(sql5);
         ps5.setString(1, user);
         rs5 = ps5.executeQuery();
         String ip,ipaddress;

          while (rs5.next()) {
              if (rs5.isLast()) {
                  ip = rs5.getString("ip");
           } else {
                  ip = rs5.getString("ip") + ",";
           }
             ipaddress = ip.substring(3);
         %>  

         <%=ipaddress%>

          <% }%>
       </textarea>
   </td>
```

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace you see is most probably the whitespace between `<%=ipaddress%>` and `<% }%>`. Try:

```
<%
    ...
    ipaddress = ip.substring(3);
%><%=ipaddress%><%

}

%></textarea>
```

It is ugly, but will eliminate the unwanted whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't clear enough. What sort of formatting do you want in the textarea? In any case, textareas don't support complex formatting apart from the usual you can do with CSS.